# Laptop sudden dead (no response)

Tags: laptop, power-supply, laptop-repair

Few days back I connected my charger to my laptop which was on and within a few seconds the laptop switched off without any warnings. It wont show charging led light and wont power up at all(tried holding power button etc didnt work). I must also mention there was no burning smell. The laptop was barely a few months old. Model : Hp 14 DQ 1039 (battery is internal). From what i understand its a motherboard fault maybe due to a voltage fluctuation but i really need to know for sure since voltage fluctuation damage isnt covered by my warranty ! What could be other diagnoses than voltage fluctuation motherboard damage

Comment: I would contact the manufacturer and make arrangement to return / repair the laptop. you do not give indications of voltage fluctuations.

Comment: Usually, line voltage variation *does not* get through the power supply, unless the power line was hit by lightning. Since the battery is internal, don't waste your time trying to fix something the vendor or manufacturer should.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. Any chance it can be caused by a low voltage fluctuation of any sort ?